# Is it possible to make a photo of a plane at cruise altitude with this zoom?

Tags: zoom, superzoom, image-plane, airplanes

I came along to this photo of a plane flying at cruise altitude. I was really surprised by the level of detail and zoom this photo has. You can even see the tail number of the plane!

Is it really possible? For curiosity, what kind of equipment is needed?

Link to photo: http://kualalumpurpost.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/mh370_file_poland_reuters.jpg

Comment: One does not need zoom for that, fixed focal length is enough.

Comment: Interesting... Are you referring to photos captured from the ground? Or from another plane? This photo was captured from the ground I think.

Comment: zoom is not equal to magnification, zoom means "variable FoV", "variable magnification". Big focal length (small FoV) is what one needs for this photo, not zoom.

Comment: I do not think that is cruise altitude. That altitude is above the couds. That plane is forming a tail of water, which, I think forms at lower altitudes.

Comment: @Rafael Jet planes leave vapor trails at cruising altitude all the time.

Comment: For the conspiracy theorists...the plane depicted is Malaysia Airlines 9M-MRO, which is the plane that was flying Malaysia Airlines Flight 370 from Kuala Lumpur to Beijing that disappeared on 8 March 2014. Yet, the JPEG contains this metadata: DateTimeOriginal: 2014:03:13 20:18:41+00:00

Comment: @osullic which leads directly to http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/69010/any-tool-that-would-retrieve-the-original-date-a-photo-was-created-on-even-after and http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/53142/15871

Comment: @MichaelClark :) I immediately thought it was edited. Although, some things in that EXIF make me think it "may" be not. The EXIF has the DateTimeOriginal field and another file from another website has the DateTimeDigitized. Photographer told me to contact Reuters because he doesn't have originals, but Reuters doesn't have that photo on catalog anymore. Recovered Google cached version from the Reuters catalog page agains says March 13, 2014.

Comment: It's just as easy to edit the date/time digitized field as the date/time original field. Changing one but not the other would be a dead giveaway. Reuters probably removed the image when they determined the EXIF info had been altered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do some simple math:
Assume the plane is 20000 feet away, and 200 feet long.
Let's also assume you want to fill half the frame width (in a full-frame camera), which is 1/2 of 36 mm = 18 mm.

With B/G*d = f (where B is the size in the picture, G the size of the object, and d its distance), you get:

f = 18mm/200ft*20000ft = 1800 mm

An easier to remember way (I think) is to divide object distance by object size: 20000ft/200ft = 100, and that's the factor you need to multiply to the size you want on the picture.

1800 mm is out of the normal photographer's lens selection, but you *can* buy that. Probably a 600mm with two teleconverters is the cheapest way. Of course, you can also go for only 1/12 of the picture = 3 mm and you will need only 300 mm which most people have. Then you crop the picture down and still have enough resolution.

Note that I made wild assumptions about the size and distance of the plane. Make your own assumptions to get your own results.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I redid the calculations using effective distance from ground and I got 3600mm. Is it something that can exist in a photographer selection of tools? I am always referring to photos captured from the ground.

Comment: A pro might have a lens of maybe 2000 mm, but that's probably not what happened for this shot. Understand that a picture is for example 5600 pixel wide; your example shot has the plane at about 900 pixel, which is only 1/6 of the picture. So you save a factor of 6, and you are back to 600 mm, which most people can reach with a 100-$-tele-converter.

Comment: if you look for extremes, check http://www.popphoto.com/gallery/9-unbelievable-camera-lenses-actually-exist?image=1 (1200 mm). There is also a sheikh who got a 10000 mm lens built, for over a million $.

Comment: You also need a good support. A sturdy tripod.

Comment: There are no commercially available 2000mm photographic lenses. The Air Force, CIA, and NSA and their international counterparts may have a few for high altitude and satellite recon, but no "pro" photographer that I've ever met owns a 2000mm photographic lens. For all practical purposes there's no such thing.

Comment: It's also possible to mount a telescope to a digital camera (or should that be mount a digital camera to a telescope?) I'm not sure how easy it is to track a plane flying at cruising altitude/speed though.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it really possible?

Yes.

> For curiosity, what kind of equipment is needed?

A very long focal length - or another plane.

Comment: ... and a good weather.

Comment: how long is very long?

Comment: @Pinhollow Euri not just "good weather", but more specifically, low levels of atmospheric haze. Oftentimes, that happens after heavy rain - at least where I live.

Comment: "Good weather", while perhaps necessary, does not fall under the "equipment" label.

Comment: @osullic How high is the plane flying?

Comment: @MichaelClark The question says "cruise altitude", so for a large airliner, probably between 30,000 and 40,000 feet.

Comment: Anywhere between FL250 and FL400 is considered cruise altitude. If you're on the ground in Denver, CO, that's a variance of 75% - Anywhere from 19,800' to 34,800' when directly overhead.

Comment: The contrails are a good indication that the aircraft is probably above 30,000'.

Comment: @osullic How long depends on several factors: How large is the plane, how high is the plane, what is the film/sensor size of the camera, what is the desired display size and resolution, and how much one can crop from the sensor with which one is taking the photo and stay within the target resolution of the desired display size.

Comment: @MikeSowsun In the case of this particular example the contrails likely (but not conclusively) indicate that. But the main question is a little more general than the specific example linked in the body of the question.

Comment: @Michael you seem to be doing your best to avoid giving an answer ;) If you use your best judgement to estimate all the variables, what would your recommended focal length (range) be? Actually, no need - I just saw Aganju's answer - with some assumptions, at least the OP gets a ball-park focal length.

Comment: @Osullic That answer has been written as well. I intentionally chose to make this answer the short and sweet version (TL:DR for all the young whippersnappers).

Answer (score 0):

1800 mm lens is the right answer for the 20000 feet, but remember, this represents a 400 foot wide field, and the plane is traveling maybe 500 MPH.  That's 733 feet/second, so it will cross the field of view in about 1/2 second, and it will be quite difficult to find it in the viewfinder in the first place. Nothing about it will be easy.

You can buy a 2000mm telescope (Celestron 8" class) for maybe $1500 US, including a tripod mount and camera mounting, and a finder scope to help aim it (works for astronomy too). Optical quality will not match a photo lens that costs many times more, and it doesn't have camera features like stops (it will be about f/10), but it could take that picture, possibly more conveniently than a camera lens (still NOT easy due to the motion). You could position ahead of the plane, and then wait for it to arrive, and hope you could catch it.

There is a calculator what will do the math for a 400 foot field at 20000 feet for various camera sensors, option 5 at http://www.scantips.com/lights/fieldofview.html